# Laravel and SQS - Several connections in one request

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a Laravel app (iOS API) that pushes data to SQS to be processed in the background.  Depending on the request, we need to dispatch anywhere from 1 to 4 jobs to SQS.  For example:

Dispatch a job to SQS, to be processed by a Worker:

- for connecting to a socket service (Pusher)
- for connecting to Apple's APNS service (Push Notifications)
- for sending data to Loggly for basic centralized request logging
- for storing analytics data in a SQL database (for the time being)

The problem is, we might have a feature like "chat", which is a pretty light request as far as server processing is concerned, however it needs to connect to SQS three times over to send:

- 1) Socket push to all the devices
- 2) Analytics processing
- 3) Centralized Request / Error Logging

In total, these connections end up doubling or tripling the time that the rest of request takes.  ie. POSTing to `/chat` might otherwise take about **40-50ms**, but with SQS, it takes more like **100 - 120ms**

Should i be approaching this differently?  Is there a way batch these to SQS so we only need to connect once rather than 3 times?

Comment: You mean like with a [SendMessageBatchRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSQSSendMessageBatchRequest.html)?  You can send up to 10 messages in a single request, as long as their combined length <= 256 KiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael suggests in the comments, one way to do it is to use a [sendMessageBatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sqs.SqsClient.html#_sendMessageBatch) request to send up to 10 messages to **one single queue**. When you're using multiple queues, and maybe even if you're not, there's also another approach.

If you can approach all the different messages as the same element, namely a notification of an action to an arbitrary receiver, you will find yourself in the fanout pattern. This is a commonly used pattern in which multiple receivers need to act on a single message, a single action.

Although AWS SQS doesn't natively support it, in combination with AWS Simple Notification Service you can actually achieve the same thing. Jeff Barr wrote a [short blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/) on the fanout setup using SNS and SQS a while ago (2012). It boils down to sending a notification to SNS that'll trigger messages to be posted on multiple SQS queues.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious, I released an MIT package to batch dispatch :)
https://packagist.org/packages/atymic/laravel-bulk-sqs-queue

It uses async and `sendMessageBatch` under the hood.